# SSRS substitutes font when printing or exporting to PDF

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I've come across a handful of questions relating to older version of SSRS/SQL Server but nothing recent relating to this issue with SQL Server 2012.  I cannot understand why this apparent bug would not be fixed when reported since SQL Server 2008.

Anyone, my question, has anyone had a similar issue and found a solution to a report in SSRS looking fine when previewed in Visual Studio as well as the default view on the server?  Yet when I print preview, print or export to PDF, my selected font of Garamond is being replaced by a generic MS Sans Serif.  Exporting to Word and Excel do not seem to suffer this bug.  If you look at the properties in the resulting PDF, the Garamond is not there, just two generic MS fonts.  When printing, the text flows as if the Garamond is there but words are being chopped off in every element on the page.

Comment: Is that font installed on the ssrs server?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently other users have had this **bug** and submitted an issue to Microsoft.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/546276/ssrs-report-printing-the-wrong-font

It's **over 5 years old** and while it is still **open**, Microsoft hasn't said that they will fix it which means **they probably never will** - even though there are no workarounds.

Here's another one from 7 years ago that was closed for no reason:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/403130/sql-reporting-services-2008-print-rendering-issue-font-replacement-font-missing-character-space-compression

They have some threshold of how many people experience the error **AND** follow the proper Microsoft procedure (like have lengthy instructions so they can repro) for reporting it (so about 1 in 10,000) before they think about addressing an issue. If enough people ask, they'll probably change this **Bug** from **Active** to **Works As Designed**.